# How to verify\check hardening of an Azure VM?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, dsc

I install hardening feature on my Azure VM with DSC. With this script: https://luke.geek.nz/Using-dsc-for-windows-hardening

How do I know it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is: it depends on how you "installed" the dsc script to the VM, but generally you can just do `Test-DSCconfiguration -Verbose` on the node. It will run through resources in the configuration and tell you which ones are compliant and which arent.

Another option would be to look at the output of how you applied the dsc script. say, if its an arm template it would return "ok" if everything worked, etc